# count () as something

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join, inner-join

I have the following table:
categories:

```
cat_id | cat_cat | cat_name
     1 |       0 | name1
     2 |       0 | name2
     3 |       1 | name3
     4 |       2 | name4
     5 |       2 | name5
     6 |       0 | name6
     7 |       1 | name7
```

I am trying to select all the categories with cat_cat=0, and selecting a count of every record that has cat_cat as the current cat_id, essentially giving me the following result:

```
cat_id | cat_cat | cat_name | cat_subcats
     1 |       0 | name1    |           2
     2 |       0 | name2    |           2
     6 |       0 | name7    |           0
```

I have tried multiple queries and my current one is as follows:

```
SELECT i.* , COUNT( i2.icon_id ) AS subcats
FROM themes_icons i, themes_icons i2
WHERE i.icon_cat =  '0'
    AND i2.icon_cat = i.icon_id
GROUP BY i.icon_cat, i2.icon_id
ORDER BY i.icon_order ASC
```

This query seems to give me the following results:

```
cat_id | cat_cat | cat_name | cat_subcats
     1 |       0 | name1    |           1
     1 |       0 | name1    |           1
     2 |       0 | name2    |           1
     2 |       0 | name2    |           1
     6 |       0 | name7    |           0
```

Anyone know how I can get the desired results. I've tried join statements too, but they keep giving me back errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is in the themes_icons table?

Comment: @JohnFX He probably renamed the tables in his example and copied the query with his real table names.

Comment: Yes indeed, what cularis said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.cat_id, c1.cat_cat, c1.cat_name,
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM categories c2
  WHERE c2.cat_cat=c1.cat_id
) AS cat_subcats
FROM categories c1
WHERE c1.cat_cat=0
```

Its a standard `SELECT`, except the subselect that counts the subcategories for the current category.